# SQL display two results side-by-side

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, and am doing an ordered select on each of them. I wold like to see the results of both orders in one result.

Example (simplified):

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY visits;"
name|# of visits
----+-----------
 AA | 5
 BB | 9
 CC | 12
.
.
.

"SELECT * FROM table2 ORDER BY spent;"
name|$ spent
----+-------
 AA | 20
 CC | 30
 BB | 50
.
.
.
```

I want to display the results as two columns so I can visually get a feeling if the most frequent visitors are also the best buyers. (I know this example is bad DB design and not a real scenario. It is an example)

I want to get this:

```
name by visits|name by spent
--------------+-------------
 AA           | AA
 BB           | CC
 CC           | BB
```

I am using SQLite.

Comment: which Database ?? SQL server? mysql? Oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    Select A.Name as NameByVisits, B.Name as NameBySpent
    From (Select C.*, RowId as RowNumber From (Select Name From Table1 Order by visits) C) A
    Inner Join
    (Select D.*, RowId as RowNumber From (Select Name From Table2 Order by spent) D) B
    On A.RowNumber = B.RowNumber
```

Comment: This gives a full cross join (9 rows in the above example)

Comment: I will edit it shortly to give you an improved answer using RowId.

Comment: Ok Edited using Rowid after Ordering each table. Then I used Inner join to connect the tables using that RowID.

Comment: Still won't work. The rowid will be the rowid of the original table, not of the sorted temporary one. This would work if doing the selects into temporary tables and then doing the main select (3 steps, but it works). That is what I ended up doing.

Comment: In Oracle (which I use it worked)
I use a double select for each table so the RowId should refer to the sorted table.
If you look carefully at my query it is 3 steps (i.e. 3 selects in depth)
If it works with RowNum (in oracle) I dont see why it wouldn't work here. But I'm glad I helped nevertheless..

Comment: SQlite is not Oracle. In SQLite only real tables have a rowid, not temporary in-memory tables.

Comment: I see...I looked up RowId but didn't see that detail. Well like I said I was trying to help out since its resolved I could remove my answer to avoid confusing others. You might want to edit your post with what you did.

Comment: You're answer was what worked. I just separated it into 3 steps.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is not a direct answer, but I was searching for it so in case someone needs it: this is a simpler solution for when the results are only one per column:

```
select 
   (select roleid from role where rolename='app.roles/anon') roleid, -- the name of the subselect will be the name of the column
   (select userid from users where username='pepe') userid;          -- same here
```

Result:

```
                 roleid                |                userid
 --------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
  31aa33c4-4e66-4da3-8525-42689e46e635 | 12ad8c95-fbef-4287-9834-7458a4b250ee
```

Comment: This may have not been the solution for this particular issue, but your "Select roleid from role' solution simplified and answered my issue trying to put three select statements side-by-side with minmal coding... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select 
    ISNULL(ts.rn,tv.rn), 
    spent.name, 
    visits.name 
from 
(select *, (select count(*) rn from spent s where s.value>=spent.value ) rn from spent) ts  
    full outer join
(select *, (select count(*) rn from visits v where v.visits>=visits.visits ) rn from visits) tv     
    on ts.rn = tv.rn
order by ISNULL(ts.rn,tv.rn)
```

It creates a rank for each entry in the source table, and joins the two on their rank. If there are duplicate ranks they will return duplicates in the results.

Answer (score 1):

For RDBMS that support common table expressions and window functions (e.g., SQL Server, Oracle, PostreSQL), I would use:

```
WITH most_visited AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY num_visits) AS num, name, num_visits
  FROM visits
),
most_spent AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY amt_spent) AS num, name, amt_spent
  FROM spent
)
SELECT mv.name, ms.name
FROM most_visited mv INNER JOIN most_spent ms
ON mv.num = ms.num
ORDER BY mv.num
```

Answer (score 0):

Just join table1 and table2 with name as key like bellow:

```
select a.name, 
   b.name, 
   a.NumOfVisitField, 
   b.TotalSpentField 
from table1 a
left join table2 b on a.name = b.name
```

Comment: I don't want them joined by name. This will give me the results of one name in the same row, while I want the best buyer and the best visitor in one row (even with different names)