# How to make subqueries to be as a columns in result query?

Tags: mariadb

There is `staff` table:

```
ID  Position Name
-----------------
1   doctor   Joe
2   nurse    Frederica
3   doctor   Mark
4   doctor   James
5   doctor   Ema
6   nurse    Dominica
7   nurse    Anna
```

How to make result query looking like this (?):

```
doctors  nurses
---------------
Joe      Frederica
Mark     Dominica
James    Anna
Ema
```

I tried something like:

```
SELECT
(SELECT staff.`Name` FROM staff WHERE staff.Position = 'doctor') AS Doctors;
(SELECT staff.`Name` FROM staff WHERE staff.Position = 'nurse') AS Nurses;
```

but as I expected, it does not work. My knowledge of SQL syntax is limited and it is quite hard to google the solution for this specific problem.

thanx a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL display two results side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065105/sql-display-two-results-side-by-side)   (found doing: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+select+two+columns+side+by+side+SQL%20site:stackoverflow.com  because of the "it is quite hard to google the solution" )

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this *exact* output, we can achieve it on MySQL 8+, using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Position ORDER BY ID) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN Position = 'doctor' THEN Name END) AS doctors,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Position = 'nurse'  THEN Name END) AS nurses
FROM cte
GROUP BY rn
ORDER BY rn;
```

Comment: unfortunately, my MariaDb version is 10.0.35, so it does not support windows functions ROW_NUMBER(), etc... Perhaps your code is correct, but I can not confirm that...

Answer (score -1):

It is a little bit complex for SQL syntax. You can get help from SQL windows functions such as Over() and Row_Number(). I created a table as you describe and when I test the SQL query below, I get the same result you need.

Here is my sample table as **staff**

```
1   doctor  Joe
2   nurse   Frederica
3   doctor  Mark
4   doctor  James
5   doctor  Ema
6   nurse   Dominica
7   nurse   Anna
```

Here is the query:

```
Select *
  From ( Select Max(Case When position = 'doctor' Then name End ) As doctors, 
                   Max(Case When position = 'nurse' Then name End ) As nurses
           From (Select Row_Number() Over(Partition By position Order By id ) As rn, 
                        position, 
                        name
                   From staff) t
          Group By rn
       )
 Order By doctors Desc Nulls Last, 
          nurses Desc Nulls Last;
```

P.S. I have less knowledge about MariaDB details. I wrote the answer based on my SQL knowledge.